# Weird Memory Behavior in Swift

Tags: swift, memory-management

OK... so I have no idea why this happens but:

Compare the following two lines:

```
let pointCurve: [AnyObject] = self.curve.map{NSValue(point:$0)}
```

and

```
let pointCurve: [NSPoint] = self.curve.map{$0}
```

In either case, the variable is local and not used at all after assignment. The line resides in a method that is called repeatedly and very quickly. The first case results in terrible and ever faster growing of memory usage. But when I change it to the second, the memory stats are flat as a disc.

You may say, "oh, you're not doing anything in the second line".  So I tried the following:

```
var pointCurve: [AnyObject] = []
for c in self.curve {
    pointCurve.append(NSValue(point:NSPoint(x:1, y:1))
}
```

vs

```
var pointCurve: [NSPoint] = []
for c in self.curve {
    pointCurve.append(NSPoint(x: 1, y: 1))
}
```

Now I see the exact same results. The culprit seems to be NSValue. I checked with Instruments that a whole bunch of `NSConcreteValues` are allocated, and I read online these are related to NSValue. But I didn't find anything about them causing memory leaks.

The question is what can I do about this. I'm supposed to send an array of points to some ObjC code, and until I figure out how to fix this, I can't do it without huge performance issues.

Comment: Why do you think the `NSValue`s are leaking? They're being allocated and stored in the `pointCurve` array. Are you saying they're still around after `pointCurve` is deallocated?

Comment: @GregoryHigley Well, memory keeps growing steadily with the size of the array. But it should be deallocated at the end of each call, no? The moment I stop calling the method (it's triggered by a mouse move event, so when I stop moving the mouse) the memory usage stops growing. When I start calling it again, usage escalates again from where it stopped the previous time. None of this happens when I don't use NSValue, no matter if I call the method or not the memory stays stable.

Comment: Try wrapping your function body in `autoreleasepool { }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
func pointCurvy() {
    autoreleasepool {
        let pointCurve: [AnyObject] = self.curve.map{NSValue(point:$0)}            
        // Do something with pointCurve.
    }
}
```

Comment: This... seems to work pretty well. Memory increase went from ~.3mb/sec to .1mb every ten seconds or so. I still see more memory usage than without using `NSValue`. This being usage that doesn't seem to decrease afterwards. Would you care to explain why things are better and why this is necessary in an ARC Swift project?

Comment: I can only speculate. I'm not sure how Swift implements arrays, but I suspect that something like `[NSPoint]` is quite a bit more efficient than `[NSValue]`. The latter may be implemented by `NSArray` under the hood, but I strongly doubt that `[NSPoint]` is.

Comment: As for the ARC issue, again I can only speculate. The behavior you were seeing smelled of objects being added to an autorelease pool whose drain had not been emptied yet. (Probably because you're calling your function repeatedly before hitting the bottom of the run loop.) As for *why* that's occurring, I have no idea.

Comment: Oh, and the reason your `[NSPoint]` didn't have the same problem is that `NSPoint`s aren't added to an autorelease pool.

Comment: Thanks! I learned I have to read more on ObjC's (/Swifts) ARC model. Will be doing that.